# More Elegant Buttons to submit data to script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping someone can help

I have the following script part

```
function buttonOneClick(){
        sendData= "map_icon=car";
        initialize();
    }

function buttonTwoClick(){
        sendData= "map_icon=boat";
        initialize();
    }
function buttonThreeClick(){
        sendData= "map_icon=motorcycle";
        initialize();
    }
function buttonfourClick(){
        sendData= "map_icon=services";
        initialize();
    }
```

The above functions could easily go to about 50 buttons like these

```
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="buttonOneClick()">Cars</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="buttonTwoClick()">Boats</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="buttonThreeClick()">Motorcycles</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" onclick="buttonfourClick()">Services</button>
```

again for each function I have a button

is there a more elegant way to create the function that handles the buttons?

example: How do I create one function to handle all the buttons?

The `sendData` is a variable which I could easily add to the button from the database

I am using JavaScript, jquery, Ajax, PHP and a MYSQL db and can create a loop for the buttons.

Comment: You're really *not* using jQuery

Comment: Hi Graham, I am using Jquery in other parts of the script

Comment: You made Chuck Norris angry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give each button an attribute, telling the script what icon it should have. You can use [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-%2a) attributes. Then bind onto a shared selector for each button (I chose to give each button an `iconbtn` class):

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".iconbtn").click(function() {
    sendData= "map_icon=" + $(this).data("icon");
    initialize();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" class="iconbtn" data-icon="car">Cars</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" class="iconbtn" data-icon="boat">Boats</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" class="iconbtn" data-icon="motorcycle">Motorcycles</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" class="iconbtn" data-icon="services">Services</button>
```

Comment: Also, if you're using jQuery UI, you might want to use something other than `data-icon` which I'm fairly sure is used by jQuery UI

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest adding a data attribute to each link:

```
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-icon="map_icon=car">Cars</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary"  data-icon="map_icon=boat">Boats</button>
```

Then you can create a single click handler for all buttons:

```
 $(function(){
     $('button').click(function(e){
         var sendData = $(this).attr('data-icon');
         initialize();
     });
 });
```

Note I removed the inline click handlers, which makes things a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Make a button like this:

```
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-send-data="map_icon=car">Cars</button>
```

Add jQuery like so:

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var sendData = $(this).data('send-data');
        initialize();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="some-container">
   <button class="large-button" mapIcon="foo1" >Click</button>
   <button class="large-button" mapIcon="foo2" >Cancel</button>
   <button class="large-button" mapIcon="foo3" >Help</button>
</div>

<script>
   jQuery("#some-container").on("click",".large-button",function(e){
   var theButton=jQuery(e.target);
   var icon=theButton.attr("mapIcon");
      initialize(icon);
   }
</script>
```

//Note the example is using **on()** function that binds the click event even for dynamic loads.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the buttons (all need the same class) and use an onclick handler with the following code

```
sendData= "map_icon="+this.innerHTML;
initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery, it would look like this:

**HTML**

```
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-icon="car">Cars</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-icon="boat">Boats</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-icon="motorcycle">Motorcycles</button>
<button type="btn btn-mini btn-primary" data-icon="services">Services</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // otherwise the button would submit to a new page
        sendData = 'map_icon=' + $(this).data('icon')
        initialize();
    });
});
```